# Can't move gnuplots into subfolder

Tags: luatex, plot, gnuplot

I have a `data.dat`-file that I plot with a `gnuplot.plt` file with these mentionable lines:

```
set term cairolatex pdf
set output "plot.tex"
```

This generate a `plot.tex`, with labels, axes, etc and a `plot.pdf` with the frame of the plot and the lines.

In my `main.tex` I include it like this:

```
\begin{figure}
    \input{plot}
\end{figure}
```

The problems is this:

If the `plot.tex` and `plot.pdf` is located in the same folder as my `main.tex` everything works fine,  but if I move the files into my `pictures/`-sub folder and change the     \begin{figure} to:

```
\begin{figure}
    \input{pictures/plot}
\end{figure}
```

I get this error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `plot' not found.
```

It would be nice to hide all my files in a sub-folder so I don't have to look at them, but I can not get this to work.

Any suggestions?

My system is:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017/Debian)
gnuplot 5.0 patchlevel 7
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Since you generate two files, `plot.tex` and `plot.pdf`, the `plot.pdf` is probably included in `plot.tex` with `\includegraphics{plot.pdf}`. Change this line in `plot.tex` to `\includegraphics{pictures/plot.pdf}`. TeX does not keep track of the directories the sub files are in, so you have to supply the path in all files.

Comment: I can include anything else from the subfolders, yes. I suspect this has to do with the fact that there are two files and not a single one.

Changing the path in `plot.tex` to include `pictures/plot.tex`, DID help, but then I would have to change my plot.tex-files every time I update the plot. And I would like avoid this.

Comment: In this case, you can put *all* you figures in `pictures` and put `\graphicspath{{./pictures/}}` in your preamble, then every picture will be assumed to be in that folder.

Comment: Very nice. With this I could add sub-sub folders as needed. This satisfies my question

Comment: Do you want me to post it as an answer?

Comment: Yes. Internet points to everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you generate the file with `gnuplot`, the `plot.tex` file calls `plot.pdf` with something like:

```
\includegraphics{plot}
```

But TeX does not keep track of the directories the sub files are in. Relative paths are all in respect to the main .tex file.

Then the correct path of the `plot.pdf` file is `pictures/plot.pdf`.

You have two options now:

1. Edit the `plot.tex` and put the correct path in `\includegraphics`. This is a one-time solution. If you generate `plot.tex` again, you'll have to fix it again.
2. Put `\graphicspath{{./pictures/}}` in your preamble, so that *every* figure you include will be assumed to be in this folder. This will affect all figures you try to include in your document.